# Appoggiatura and acciaccatura

Tags: theory, sheet-music, ornaments

Can you write the appoggiatura and acciaccatura **after** a note? I have always seen it before a note.

Comment: It wouldn't then be acciacatura and appoggiatura, it would be something very different, for which I don't think there is a term.

Answer (score 2):

In terms of the *notation*, they are considered to belong *before* the next note, not *after* the previous note.

But in terms of performance, in some situations they *do* belong to the previous note.

For example they might represent a "twiddle" at the end of a note with a trill. In that case, they can be separated from the next note by a bar line. That notation is more common in the early classical period (when appoggiaturas were not yet an extinct species of ornament) than in the baroque, where it was usually left up to the performer.

Also, in some (fairly rare) situations, an appoggiatura takes time from the previous note not the following one. Read a good book on ornamentation, or some contemporary sources (e.g. CPE Bach on "The True Art of playing Keyboard Instruments") for details - the story is too long to explain here!

Answer (score 0):

Not in standard notation. I take no responsibility for what a modernist composer might notate for his own special purposes though!